# Discord.js check if a user nickname contains Numbers and Letter, if yes add calculation to the number

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm looking for a way to check if a discord users name contains numbers and certain letter, and if it does then apply a calculation to it.

For example I have a command that right now checks if the user has anything in the nickname, this adds the additional number next to the previous one (if there is one), if he doesn't have anything as a nickname it makes the nickname  `UserName - {number} PRs`. I'm looking for a way a to check if the user has `{number} PRs` in their name and if so, add the `multiplyNum` calculation to the existing number and preserve the rest of the name.

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'test',
    cooldown: 1000,
    run: async(client, message, args) => {
        let member = message.mentions.members.first();
        var multiplyNum = args[0] * ((100 - 50) / 100) * 0.23;
        var finalNum = multiplyNum.toFixed(2);

        let memberNick = member ? member.displayName : null;

        if (member.nickname){
            if(!member) return message.channel.send("Invalid User");
            member.setNickname(`${memberNick}` + ", " + `${finalNum}` + " PRs");

        }else{
            if(!member) return message.channel.send("Invalid User");
            member.setNickname(`${memberNick}` + " - " + `${finalNum}` + " PRs");

        };

    }
```

Comment: Could you provide example of args?

Comment: You would type `_test 50 @user` the 50 is the variable number

Comment: You need to regex it, then extract the number from that. Ill take a look into it. + I don't know what you are doing with those nicknames but remind you that users can change their nicknames.

Comment: I disabled the permisions for nickname changes, so it should be fine. only way to change it is if they change their name on discord and if they do that you can see that their name is not a nickname.

Comment: OK so I gave it about 5 minutes and I am confident that I don't know how to compactly regex something like `David Quetta ㄱㅁㅇㄱ 你哈 508 PRs` or nickname made only of spaces etc. Unless you enforce name policy I think this will become almost impossible to solve this way and as of now I cannot think of any other way to do it.

Comment: What if I only target the number? And I can just have the bot copy the nickname again and add the PRs behind the number. It's an english speaking server so most people don't have different character names. If they do it can manually be changed as only admins will be able to use the command

Comment: If you can assure that the nickname will always and with ` ${number} PRs`. You can take the last number in the nickname and completely ignore rest of the nickname and splice the old nickname and then put it together. Doing that would I think be quite easy. Good idea tbh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do I think. What you do is that you make nickname into array that splited by spaces and if last key is PRs and last key -1 is !NaN you run the calculation otherwise nothing is done.

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'test',
    cooldown: 1000,
    run: async(client, message, args) => {
        let member = message.mentions.members.first();
        var multiplyNum = args[0] * ((100 - 50) / 100) * 0.23;
        var finalNum = multiplyNum.toFixed(2);

        let memberNick = member ? member.displayName : null;

        if (member.nickname){
            if(!member) return message.channel.send("Invalid User");
            member.setNickname(`${memberNick}` + ", " + `${finalNum}` + " PRs");

        } else {
            if(!member) return message.channel.send("Invalid User");
            const nicknameAsArray = memberNick.split(" ");
            var number = nicknameAsArray[nicknameAsArray.length - 2];
            if (
              nicknameAsArray[nicknameAsArray.length - 1] === "PRs" &&
              !isNaN(Number(nicknameAsArray[nicknameAsArray.length - 2]))
            ) {
              nicknameAsArray[nicknameAsArray.length - 2] = Number(number) * multiplyNum;

              member.setNickname(nicknameAsArray.join(" "));
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: It works great, I just had to put it in the `if` instead of `else` because then It targets when the user doesn't have a nickname already and therefore does nothing haha.